# Creating an ASM file that will return the characters located in 8 consecutive registers

Tags: assembly, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I have to create an ASM file for the PIC18F452 that does the following:

(a) define the label `MapName` as the first of 8 consecutive registers containing a null-terminated string of not more than 7 characters. (b) access an 8-bit unsigned integer variable called `MapIndex` which was declared in a C file. (c) define an ASM function `getMapChar` which can be called from C using the function prototype `char getMapChar(void)`. The function should return the appropriate character when the value of `MapIndex` is <= 7 or the value 255 if `MapIndex` is > 7. (d) make the labels `MapName` and `getMapChar` accessible to an external C file.

My code so far is shown below:

```
; Configuration word : WDT off, power-up timer on, code protect off, RC oscillator

list = p18f452

MapName     equ     0x20
MapName1    equ     0x21
MapName2    equ     0x22
MapName3    equ     0x23
MapName4    equ     0x24
MapName5    equ     0x25
MapName6    equ     0x26
MapName7    equ     0x27
CurrentChar equ     0x28

extern  MapIndex

org 0x00
goto    getMapChar

getMapChar
    movlw   0x00
    movwf   MapName7

GLOBAL  getMapChar
GLOBAL  MapName

    END
```

I have already done parts (a), (b) and (d) but I am having some problems with writing the code that moves through each of the consecutive registers automatically using the value of `MapIndex`. Could anyone help me please? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ To all users - I posted this question on electronics.stackoverflow.com, and I was advised to move to question to here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of **FSR** (file select registers) to address **MapName** file registers:

```
lfsr    0, MapName      ;Load 12bit file address pointer to FSR0
movf    MapIndex, w     ;Load MapIndex to WREG  ; or movff MapIndex, WREG
addwf   FSR0L, f        ;Add MapIndex to FSR0 low byte
movf    INDF0, w        ;Load MapName[MapIndex] to WREG
```

If all file registers of variable **MapName** aren't inside 8 bit address space then after adding **MapIndex** to **FSR0L** check **Carry** flag for overflow. If **Carry** is set increase also the **FSR0H** file register.